# How to search for DiscriminatorType in INNER JOIN FETCH-ed class in JPQL?

Tags: hibernate, entity, inner-join, jpql, single-table-inheritance

I have 3 java class with SINGLE_TABLE inheritance, as you see:

The MessageTemplate parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message_template")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="MESSAGE_TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("message_template")
public class MessageTemplate {
    private String campaignName;
    private String subject;
    private String text;
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    //gettersetter...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "template")
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

The EmailTemplate extends from MessageTemplate:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EMAIL")
public class EmailTemplate extends MessageTemplate {
    //some properties
}
```

The SmsTemplate extends from MessageTemplate:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SMS")
public class SmsTemplate extends MessageTemplate{
    //some properties
}
```

You can see, there is `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

I want to create a jpql sql select, where I could search for parameters, AND also search for class type! I wrote something, but it hasn't worked:

```
String sql = "SELECT msg FROM message INNER JOIN FETCH msg.template WHERE TYPE(msg.template) IN :class";
Query q = em.createQuery(sql.toString());
q.setParameter("class", EmailTemplate.class);
```

But I'am getting error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: class of: com.khb.rrm.entity.Message [SELECT msg FROM com.khb.rrm.entity.Message msg WHERE TYPE(msg.template) IN :class]
```

But I can search for other properties, like:

```
String sql = "SELECT msg FROM message INNER JOIN FETCH msg.template WHERE msg.template.subject LIKE :subject";
Query q = em.createQuery(sql.toString());
q.setParameter("subject", "%something subject%");
```

How could I search for class type in inner join fetch types? Thank you!

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? See issue here when querying for types: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4881

Comment: hibernate version = 3.6.3.Final

Comment: thank you for the link, it showed me something good!